# Entity Framework stops when run on Win7, .NET 4

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have a winforms application with entitity framework 6.1
on my w8.1 vs2013 it runs fine, on my w7 vs2010 the run stops when I try an Linq query without error in a try catch. The program stops, but visual studio seems to be still running.
On both machines the application targets .net 4

I found that on the w7 I have  framework 4 version 4.5.50938 and on my w8.1 I have version 4.5.51641

Anybody an idea ?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: no exception, nothing happens visual studio keeps working, but no results, no breakpoints are hit